# 1:1 PGP key requirement

Tags: gnupg, pgp

We have a single encryption key in place for use by our business partners globally. This contains the main signing key as well as the encryption subkey. We have now run into a situation (with a bank) that says since our encryption key is already in use by one of their other divisions (ie in South America) to send us encrypted data, that they (Asia) are unable to utilize the same key. They state they have a 1:1 requirement, and each bank account must be linked to a unique PGP key. So are asking us for a new one.

Anyone else run into this type of situation? Generating a whole new key just to use for this one Business Partner is problematic as our setup is based on having only the single key for all partners.

Comment: Did they specifically ask for a whole new pgp "key block", or just for a new encryption subkey? (And before anyone mentions it, there _are_ technical means to make multiple pgp key blocks that actually have identical encryption subkeys, but IMHO that's really going into "high probability of pissing off your business partners when they find out" territory.)

Answer (score 0):

You could effect a small change in your setup that will satisfy the bank, by setting
an intermediary gateway for the client, with its own PGP key, that will decrypt
the message, encrypt with the common key, and finally forward to the main software.

But I would suggest changing your setup rather than risk losing a client,
and a bank in addition.